# Datatables rows().every() with ajax request inside

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

i'm trying to update an input fields inside of datatable on each row, but first i take a value from a cell and send it to ajax to get a value and then update de input field with this value.

the principal problem es that rows().every() is executed more fast than ajax and just one row is updated.

here is the code that i'm using:

```
updatePrices(0.95);

function updatePrices(freight){
  table.rows().every(function () {
   var sk = table.cell(this,2).data(); // HERE I GET THE VALUE OF DATTABLES TO SEARCH THE PRODUCT AND ITS PRICE.

   var dataString = 'sku='+ sk;

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "searchProductBySku.php",
       data: dataString,
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
       success: function(data){
          newprice = parseFloat(data[9])+parseFloat(freight);// RETURN NEW PRICE AND SUM THE FREIGHT COST


 table.cell(this,9).nodes().to$().find('input').val(parseFloat(newprice).toFixed(2)); // AND CELL WITH INPUT IS UPDATED

        }
     });
  });
 alert('Prices were updated, please check them before send this order.');

}
```

Comment: table.rows().every() runs an ajax call per row ? or the same value is used for all rows ?

Comment: ajax call per row, sku value is changing on each row

Comment: That sounds heavy , why dont use a single ajax to get all values ? I guess each row have an id value you could use those ids to populate the fields ? as example I loaded a table with datatables in some custom module I did months ago once a change was made to a row I need to get some other values and populate a new column what I did was an ajax call  with a query like this select value from new_table where new_table_reference_id in (select id from old_table)